# Async await pattern help. Am I doing it right?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, async-await

I have a "api" e.g. repository pattern, I wrote to return xml from the web and then hydrate it to classes.

It seems to hang on the result of the GetXmlAsync(url) method.

```
public async Task<string> GetXmlAsync(string url)
{
    string xml = string.Empty;

    HttpMessageHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

    xml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return xml;
}
```

But when I use the same code in a unit test, it works.

In the app, I call it like so:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> GetRecentAsync(int page)
{
    string url = this.urls.GetRecent(page);
    string xml = string.Empty;

    var xmlTask = this.loader.GetXmlAsync(url);

    xml = xmlTask.Result; // Hangs right here.

    var results = this.modelLoader.XmlToPost(xml);

    if (results.Count() < 1)
    {
        this.LastError = XmlLoadError;
    }

    return results.AsEnumerable();
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task Integration_HttpLoader_GetXmlAsync_GetRecent_Xml_ShouldNotBeNullOrEmpty()
{
    int page = 1;
    string xml = string.Empty;
    IUrl url = this.GetUrlHelper();
    ILoader loader = this.GetIntegrationLoader(false);

    xml = await loader.GetXmlAsync(url.GetRecent(page));

    Assert.IsTrue(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml));
}
```

Comment: Can you show your working unit test code?

Comment: Also, are you doing your own XML serialization to learn how it works, or is there another reason that you aren't using one of the existing serialization systems?

Comment: Adam, added the unit test. Also, because I am using linq to xml to hydrate the objects, that works great. The service doesn't do anything but xml.

Comment: Adam, my hydration routine is here: http://pastebin.com/5iEyR47r

Comment: Have you confirmed that the URLs are the same? What is the difference between `this.loader` (which, I assume, is what's used in the normal functions) and `this.GetIntegrationLoader(false)`?

Comment: IntegrationLoader is the regular loader, I have a test loader too that returns canned xml without going to the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your app, you are not preceding the call to this.loader.GetXmlAsync(url) with **await** You hit this line, fire an async task on another thread then immediately proceed to the next line without having ever gotten the response.  It works in your unit test because you correctly use the **await** keyword.

Answer (score 4):

You are [causing a deadlock](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by synchronously blocking on the result of the task.

Follow these best practices:

- Do not block on `async` code (make it `async` all the way down).

  e.g., `var xml = await this.loader.GetXmlAsync(url);` in `GetRecentAsync`.
- Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in your "library" `async` methods if they can continue on a thread pool thread.

  e.g., `var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);` and `xml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` in `GetXmlAsync`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `ConfigureAwait(false)`, but it's important to be clear that you must be sure that anything following your awaited code must be safe to run on any thread. No direct updating of UI properties, for example.

Comment: Excellent point, Adam. I've updated my answer to reflect this.